# Create a list of taxonomy terms which filter specific nodes

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I would like to add a list of taxonomy "links" within my view so when ever a user clicks a specific term, only nodes tagged with that term will show up in the view.

Is there a module that can create a navigation of taxonomy terms within a view, to filter for specific nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to install module. create a field of taxonomy terms, in the view create a contextual filter of that field and it will work.

---

To create a navigation you need to loop through the taxonomy terms. it is something like this code. I am not able to execute the code right now to give you the exact code but using Devel module and looping (`foreach`)throught the objects you can get the terms and use them to build the navigation.

```
$name = 'YOUR_VOCAB_NAME';
$myvoc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
print kpr($myvoc);
```

This code will print out the list of terms and their properties.

Comment: Well thanks in first place, but how to create a navigation providing the taxonomy terms?

Comment: @fubbe I updated the answer, I will you give you the exact code n a few hours

Comment: You don't have to, I got it from this point on! Thanks a lot

Comment: @fubbe If you think this answer is useful, mark it as accepted for people who visit your question in the future